# Does the bulk of heavy armor include the bulk of the included padded armor and gauntlets

Tags: pathfinder-2e, encumbrance

Nearly every heavy armor in Pathfinder 2nd edition includes the following in its description:

> A suit of this armor comes with an undercoat of padded armor and a pair of gauntlets.

Does the bulk of the armor include the bulk of the padded armor and gauntlets?

For example, splint mail has a bulk of 3, padded armor has a bulk of L, and a single gauntlet has a bulk of 3L. When I purchase splint mail, do I acquire a bulk of 3 or “3 + 3L”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It likely does include the bulk

The rules do not say *explicitly* that the bulk given in an entry for equipment includes all items that you get when you buy the equipment, but I think it is strongly implied.

The rules for bulk says:

> Items can have a number to indicate their Bulk value, or they can be light (indicated by an L) or negligible (indicated by a —) for the purpose of determining Bulk. For instance, full plate armor is 4 Bulk, a longsword is 1 Bulk, a dagger or scroll is light, and a piece of chalk is negligible.

The only reason to wonder is because the line says "comes with" instead of "includes" padded armor and gauntlets. So just the rules text is not conclusive. However, there is a history of games Pathfinder 2e derives from, all the way back to 1e D&D, where armors assumed they included helmets, as part of the overall cost and weight.

The padded armor is part of the armor that you buy, and need to be worn together with it for full effect. You otherwise buy a plate armor, sell off the gauntlets and padded armor, and still have a fully functioning plate armor, reducing its effective price (and weight, if you assume it is also included). I think it's a strech to conclude that is what is intended by this wording, given the historical background.